# Is signup feature is mandatory for ios app to upload on iTune

Tags: ios

Is apple store reject any app without signup process.
I want to develop an ios app for some specific users who login details generated by super admin from web application and with these login detail user can signin into ios app.

I am ignoring B2B app due to lengthy installation process.

Comment: If your app has a limited audience it is likely to be rejected.  If anyone is able to sign up for your web site then including a sign up capability in your app will make the user experience better.

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry for create confusion. User cant register from web application...only super admin can create user and then transfer login detail to user.
In this your view is same??

Comment: Unless you app has broad use (tens or hundreds of thousands of users) it will probably be rejected. All you can do is try.  If your app is targeted to employees of companies that use your web service then a custom B2B app may well be the best solution. If devices are managed by an MDM then B2B app install is straightforward.